# how to reset form using javascript/jquery after sending form information

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to reset form using jquery/javascript i dont know why doesnt this working ,everytime when i try to reset the form using javascript and jquery sometimes it totally stop then clears the form or it says error of some line which is   `x[i].getElementsByTagName("message")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue` inside a loop ,
I have tried `onclick="this.form.reset()"` inside the form input button it clears but doesnt work the same above error i have tried many different approch but not working here is my code below

Edit- i have an xml file

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function fetch() {

        setTimeout( function() {
        loadDoc();
        fetch();
    }, 100);

}


function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      myFunction(this);
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "../clubs/club.xml", true);
  xhttp.send();
}

$(function() {
    $("#formpost").submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var form = $(this);
        var url = form.attr('action');

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: form.serialize() // serializes the form's elements.
        }).done(function(data) {
            var msg = $(data).find('#msg').text();


        });
    });
});  

  function myFunction(xml) {
  var rowsArray =[]
  var i , j;
  var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
  var table="";
  var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("messageset");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  var name = x[i].getElementsByTagName("name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
  var time = x[i].getElementsByTagName("time")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    var row = "<div class=\"row\"><div class=\"b1\" ><img src=\"" + "../users/"    
    + name +"/notification/profilepic.svg" + "\" width=\"30px\" height=\"30x\" alt=\"avatar\" style=\"border-radius: 45px;\" class=\"image\" ></div><div class=\"b2 msginname\" >" +
    x[i].getElementsByTagName("name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "</div> <div class=\"cmoti \"><a href=\"online.php\">check motive</a></div><div class=\"msgoriginal\">" +
    x[i].getElementsByTagName("message")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "</div></div>";
    rowsArray.push(row)
  }
  table += rowsArray.reverse().join('');
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = table;
  document.getElementById("check").innerHTML = time ;
}
function myFun(){
 $('#formpost').click(function(){
        $('#formpost')[0].reset();
  });
}
</script>
```

Comment: What does _I have tried this.form.reset() inside the form it clears but doesnt working_ actually mean? A cleared form has been reset. A form on which the action of resetting it "doesn't working" has not been cleared.

You're being entirely unclear.

Comment: submit on form button

Comment: You're not making any sense. Start talking in complete sentences - ones that dont contradict one-another. I'm out - it shouldn't be this hard to help someone for $0.

Comment: i have edited the question that point can you have a look

Comment: You've got two separate and distinct problems here. (0) resetting a form and (1) iterating over data that doesn't contain what you think it does. They're unrelated to each other. The simple-enough `form.reset()` is enough to clear it. The other problem though is because you're expecting something that isn't there. This is the perfect time to become better friends with your browser's debugger. You haven't provided a runnable example or the clubs.xml file - this prevents users from testing. You'll almost certainly need to solve this with your new best buddy, the debugger.

Comment: i want to clear after sending the data values

Answer (score 0):

You can use reset function.Use it on the base of ajax response

```
document.getElementById("formid").reset();        // Reset form values after form submission
```

Comment: @Anjali - Are you saying that you called reset, then tried to submit the form, only to find the submission results empty?